# How to write a random parameter of request url in Apiary

Tags: apiary

I have a request url with a parameter which is random in nature example : /abc/jhdidjkljd/123
the number keeps changing .
I am searching a way to write the parameter in such a way that i can mock the target .

Comment: Not clear what is random. Just the number 123 at the end of your example? or do you have /{param1}/{param2}/{param3} where each of the param(n) is completely random, yet a consistent pattern or are you saying the path is completely random? Please clarify.

Comment: Only the param3. It's a 3 digit numeric value: 
/abc/jhdidjkljd/{random number}.
Keeps changing .

Comment: I have found a solution : in apiary replace the number with {id} like this : /abc/jhdidjkljd/{id}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URL Templates](http://support.apiary.io/knowledgebase/articles/106871-uri-templates-support):

```
    FORMAT: 1A

    # Customer Testing

    ## Resource ID [/{id}]

    + Parameters
        + id (required, string, `xoxo`) ... ID

    ## Query an Existing Job [GET]

    + Request (application/json)

            {
                "key": "value"
            }

    + Response 204
```